# show posts in archive page based on selected catagory

Tags: categories

I want to display posts in one page depending on a selected category in the menu, without loading the archive page of the category. a any idea on how it can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following code for category name

```
 'The_Category_Name', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );

// The Loop
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    echo '</li>';
    the_title();
    echo '</li>';
    endwhile;

// Reset Query
wp_reset_query();

?>
```

Here replace The_Category_Name by name of your category